# Picking post numbers reveals titles of deleted questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, title, 404-not-found

If you change the post number in any question URL to a number of a deleted question, you will be redirected to a 404 page, but the URL in your address bar will change to contain the title of the deleted question.

Example URL, try it in private browsing mode: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339451/

Works with "q" and "a" links too, but not "posts" links.

This works while logged in, but the fact that it also works while logged out, in my opinion, is much worse.

Comment: What makes you think this is a bug?  Deleted questions can be viewed by users with enough reputation.

Comment: @Ramhound sure, but users without that rep should not be able to see the deleted posts.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard - This question does not indicate the deleted contribution can be viewed, just the title of the question, and honestly the reproduction steps aren't all that clear.

Comment: @Ramhound title might contain the question. Anyway, it's information leak.